# Why would I need to list -ldl before a library that calls dlopen/dlclose/dlerror when linking

Tags: c++, linker, g++, rhel

I am building an executable (foo.exe let's call it) on RHEL with gcc 6.2. It links against a few third-party libraries, libzzdesign.so, libyydesign.so. Yydesign uses dlopen/dlclose/dlerror. I would expect this command-line to work:
`g++ -Wall -fcheck-new -fno-strict-aliasing -msse2 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread -O3 -Wl,--export-dynamic -o foo.exe foo.o -L/path/to/zzdesign -Wl,-rpath=/path/to/zzdesign -lzzdesign -L/path/to/yydesign -Wl,-rpath=/path/to/yydesign -lyydesign -ldl`
(I'm listing all the options used in case it matters)

It produces the errors,
`/path/to/yydesign/libyydesign.so: undefined reference to 'dlclose'`
`/path/to/yydesign/libyydesign.so: undefined reference to 'dlerror'`

If I change the command line to put `-ldl` *before* `-lyydesign`:
`g++ -Wall -fcheck-new -fno-strict-aliasing -msse2 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread -O3 -Wl,--export-dynamic -o foo.exe foo.o -L/path/to/zzdesign -Wl,-rpath=/path/to/zzdesign -lzzdesign -L/path/to/yydesign -Wl,-rpath=/path/to/yydesign -ldl -lyydesign`
... it works without error.

This is the opposite of everything I thought I knew about order of libraries on the command line when linking.

1. Why does `-ldl` have to come before `-lyydesign`?
2. Other than dumb luck to stumble across this solution, how could I troubleshoot the original error to understand what's going on?
3. And since changing the build system to move -ldl first in all the places it's needed is kind of a pain, is there a way I can avoid having to put -ldl first?

Comment: If don't want to correct the dependency ordering, use `--start-group [ libs ] --end-group`.

Comment: Is it generally the case that a dependee should appear before the depender when linking? I've always heard it should be depender followed by dependee (for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc).)

Comment: This doesn't look like a thing that could possibly happen in this here universe.

Comment: It's repeatable -- both the error in the first form and success in the second. Any suggestions to further track down what's going on then?

Comment: Try to minimize it to just `-lyydesign -ldl`, without zzdesign etc. Also try with `-Wl,--no-as-needed -ldl`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the undefined reference error with *any* position of `-ldl` on the command line, from the very first to the very last.

Comment: As usual, try to produce a [mcve]. First reduce `foo.c` to a single function call to `libyydesign` and get rid of  `libzzdesign`. Second, reduce `libyydesign` to a single function that calls `dlopen`, `dlerror`, `dlclose`. Third, post it all here together with build commands *as is*, without editing a single letter.

Comment: I suspect RHEL and gcc 6 (and whatever compatibility shims redhat might have done) are an important part of the puzzle. It's not an issue with gcc 4. I'll need to make a simplified test case in order to test other OSes/versions.

Comment: I was afraid of this... the simplest test case doesn't reproduce the issue, so I'm back to question #2: how can I debug what's happening here? 
nm for both simple test case and actual library demonstrating this problem show dladdr, dlclose, dlerror, dlopen, and dlsym as undefined.

Comment: If creating a reproducible case from scratch doesn't work, then start removing code from the actual program bit by bit until you are left with the smallest amount of code possible.

Comment: Then what? I have a smaller example that still doesn't work and that I still have no way to troubleshoot.

Answer (score -2):

Order of libs for `LD` does matter. Lib `yydesign` use `dlclose` and `dlerror` that's why lib `dl` need to be passed before `yydesign`.

Comment: You've got it exactly backwards.